# How to send packets coming from a second router on a particular port back to the router, using iptables not a route

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing

I have a Linux server which runs a particular service listening on a single TCP port.
The Linux server connects to the internet using a PPP connection and also acts as router for a local network using an Ethernet connection. I keep a firewall running on this server and manage it using Shorewall package.

Recently I got another internet link to use as a redundant IP address for my clients to connect to and use the service. This ISP gives me a modem which should connect to my LAN switch and has an IP address of `192.168.1.10`. I configured this modem to forward the service port to my server which is at `192.168.1.2`.

The problem is users can not connect through the new connection to server, routing configuration on new modem is limited (I can't tell it to do SNAT) and I don't know what sort of configuration I need on the firewall on server.

In simple words I need to tell the firewall on server, when packets come from `192.168.1.10` on port 1234, send the replies back to `192.168.1.10`, despite whatever destination IP address is.

My best bet so far from my searches is http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html which requires playing with server routes.

Is there any simpler way to do this preferably using iptables and shorewall?